# Store clicks inside .txt/.php file on the server

Tags: php, html, count, store

I know that most of you will say that saving clicks inside a **.txt** or **.php** file is slower than in a DB, and I agree, but I require this...

I already have a script that stores the clicks of a single form inside a **.txt** file. The thing is that I need to use that script for multiple forms and store the clicks in the same **.txt (or .php)** file and echo the number of clicks on each button. That's what I can't achieve.

*If you have a solution for my issue and want to post an answer, please add some explanation so that I can understand why/how you did it so that I won't come asking the same questions all over again. Thanks*

Here is what I have so far :

**HMTL:**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="click me!" name="clicks">
</form>
<div>Click Count: <?php echo getClickCount(); ?></div>
```

**PHP:**

```
if( isset($_POST['clicks']) ) { 
    incrementClickCount();
}

function getClickCount()
{
    return (int)file_get_contents("clickit.txt");
}

function incrementClickCount()
{
    $count = getClickCount() + 1;
    file_put_contents("clickit.txt", $count);
}
```

> **Update** I am willing to use json for this (as I understand it can be done) but you will have to bear with me cause I never used json
>   before and even if it's easy to read/write, first time is first
>   time...

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Why do you have to write to a file? Are you aware of the problems of this solution? *Please add some explanation so that I can understand what you want so that I won't come asking the same questions all over again.*

Comment: @RoToRa Hello, my issue is that I can't use the code above for multiple buttons (well, I can but it does increment the value in the clickit.txt file for all the buttons, not individually, therefore all buttons will return the same number of clicks.). Like I said, I know it's not as fast as a database and not as secure, but I'm not worried about that. I need it for a client that want's to access it via FTP and insert it once a week in a statistics program. :) Does this answer your questions ?

Comment: you could use json to store the name of the button and it's clicks. when you use json_decode you will have PHP array/object with name/clicks. Then you could increment the clicks only for the desired button. The problem is that if you have multiple users that clicks on same time you will have data loss because of one file you use. That's why DB is preffered solution for transaction actions like this one

Comment: Can you use the CSV format?

Comment: @smokeyPHP I think that along the way I tried using commas to try an separate the values but (due to my lack of php knowledge) I couldn't achieve it...

Comment: @bksi Well, I probably could if I knew how :) didn't use json up till now, I think I might have to give it a try.

Comment: Just create and read an associative array, let `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` worry about that format in the file. It's just a string version of your array

Comment: Added Example of Multiple buttons on one form. Updated the Answer and the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store 'click counts' from individual 'html forms' in a text file. It is tested.

*Added an example of Counting Clicks using a form with  Multiple Buttons.*

*It uses the text file to store a PHP array in JSON format*

*[Working Website here](http://rfv123.eu.pn/clickcount/)*

An overview:

```
/*
 *
 * We need to store the form 'click' counts in an array:
 * i.e.
 *   array( 'form1' =>  click count for Form1,
 *          'form2' =>  click count for form2
 *          ...
 *        );
 *
 * We need a 'key' to identify the 'current' form that we are counting the clicks of.
 *   I propose that it is based on the 'url' that caused the form to be actioned.
 *
 * The idea is to create an array of 'click counts' and 'serialize' it to and from a file.
 *
 * Performance may be an issue for large numbers of forms.   
 *  
 */
```

I created a class that 'looks after' the text file.

ClickCount.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * All the code to maintain the 'Form Click Counts' in a text file...
 *
 * The text file is really an 'array' that is keyed on a 'Text String'.
 *
 * The filename format will work on 'windows' and 'unix'.
 *
 * It is designed to work reliably rather than be 'cheap to run'.
 *
 * @author rfv
 */

class ClickCount {

    const CLICK_COUNT_FILE = 'FormClickCounts.txt';

    protected $clickCounts = array();


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->loadFile();
    }


    /**
     * increment the click count for the formId
     *
     * @param string $textId - gets converted to a 'ButtonId'
     */
    public function incClickCount($textId)
    {
        $clickId = $this->TextIdlToClickId($textId);

        if (isset($this->clickCounts[$clickId])) {
            $this->clickCounts[$clickId]['click']++;
        }
        else {
            $this->clickCounts[$clickId]['textId'] = $textId;
            $this->clickCounts[$clickId]['click'] = 1;
        }

        $this->saveFile();
    }

    /**
     * Return the number of 'clicks' for a particular form.
     *
     * @param type $clickId
     * @return int clickCounts
     */
    public function getClickCount($textId)
    {
        $clickId = $this->TextIdlToClickId($textId);

        if (isset($this->clickCounts[$clickId])) {
            return $this->clickCounts[$clickId]['click'];
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return array the 'click counts' array
     */
    public function getAllClickCounts()
    {
        return $this->clickCounts;
    }

    /**
     * The file holds a PHP array stored in JSON format
     */
    public function loadFile()
    {
        $filePath = __DIR__ .'/'. self::CLICK_COUNT_FILE;
        if (!file_exists($filePath)) {
            touch($filePath);
            $this->saveFile();
        }

        $this->clickCounts = json_decode(file_get_contents($filePath), true);
    }

    /**
     * save a PHP array, in JSON format, in a file
     */
    public function saveFile()
    {
        $filePath = __DIR__ .'/'. self::CLICK_COUNT_FILE;
        file_put_contents($filePath, json_encode($this->clickCounts));
    }

    /**
     * 'normalise' a 'form action' to a string that can be used as an array key
     * @param type $textId
     * @return string
     */
    public function TextIdlToClickId($textId)
    {
        return bin2hex(crc32($textId));
    }
}
```

The 'index.php' file that runs this...

```
<?php // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28912960/store-clicks-inside-txt-php-file-on-the-server

include __DIR__ .'/ClickCount.php';

/*
 * This is, to be generous, 'proof of concept' of:
 *
 *   1) Storing click counts for individual forms in a text file
 *   2) Easily processing the data later
 */

/*
 *
 * We need to store the form 'click' counts in an array:
 * i.e.
 *   array( 'form1' =>  click count for Form1,
 *          'form2' =>  click count for form2
 *          ...
 *        );
 *
 * o We need a 'key' to identify the 'current' form that we are counting the clicks of.
 *   I propose that it is based on the 'url' that caused the form to be actioned.
 *
 * The rest i will make up as i go along...
 */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>store-clicks-inside-txt-php-file-on-the-server</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>select form...</h2>

    <p><a href="/form1.php">Form 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="/form2.php">Form 2</a></p>

    <h2>Current Counts</h2>
    <pre>
    <?php $theCounts = new ClickCount(); ?>
    <?php print_r($theCounts->getAllClickCounts()); ?>
    </pre>
</body>
```

The two form files that 'clicks' are counted...

Form 1

```
<?php
include __DIR__ .'/ClickCount.php';

// change this for your system...
define ('HOME', '/index.php');

// this looks after the 'click counts' text file
$clickCounts = new ClickCount();

if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    header("location: ". HOME);
    exit;
}

// increment the count for the current form
if (isset($_POST['clicks'])) {
    $clickCounts->incClickCount($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

?>
<h2>Form 1</h2>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="click me!" name="clicks">
    <input type="submit" value="cancel" name="cancel">
</form>
<div>Click Count: <?php echo $clickCounts->getClickCount($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?></div>
```

Form with Multiple Button:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ .'/ClickCount.php';

// change this for your system...
define ('HOME', '/clickcount/index.php');

// this looks after the 'click counts' text file
$clickCounts = new ClickCount();

if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    header("location: ". HOME);
    exit;
}

// increment the count for the current form
if (isset($_POST['clicks'])) {
    $clickCounts->incClickCount($_POST['clicks']);
}

?>
<h2>Multiple Buttons on the Form - Count the Clicks</h2>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <br /><label for="clicks1">1) Click Me</label><input type="submit" value="click me - 1!" id="clicks1" name="clicks">
    <br /><label for="clicks1">2) Click Me</label><input type="submit" value="click me - 2!" id="clicks2" name="clicks">
    <br /><label for="clicks1">3) Click Me</label><input type="submit" value="click me - 3!" id="clicks3" name="clicks">
    <br /><label for="clicks1">4) Click Me</label><input type="submit" value="click me - 4!" id="clicks4" name="clicks">
    <br /><br /><input type="submit" value="cancel" name="cancel">
</form>
<div>Click Counts:
       <?php foreach ($clickCounts->getAllClickCounts() as $counts): ?>
           <?php if (strpos($counts['url'], 'click me -') !== false): ?>
             <?php echo '<br />Counts for: ', $counts['url'], ' are: ', $counts['click']; ?>
           <?php endif ?>
       <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hei, I will test this soon, thanks for everything and the explanation, the thing is though, I was looking for an easier way of doing it, with this solution, if I have 18 buttons, I have to duplicate the Form.php 18 times, and this isn't a good idea...Anyway, I'll get back to you after I test it :)

Comment: Well, this looks promising, I will look into it and modify it according to my needs. Thanks, I will mark it as it does answer my question :) Have a great day.

Comment: @Alin, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Check this method (Not tested).

```
$my_file = 'clickit.txt';
//Read the file
$handle = file_get_contents($my_file);
//Add click
$data = $handle+1;
//Write the file
file_put_contents($my_file,$data);
```

Comment: I have tested it with two buttons and it's not working as expected (just like my version, it does increment the value in the clickit.txt file but it does so for both buttons, not individually, therefore both buttons will return the same number of clicks.)

Comment: what is php version you are using? R u stuck with fopen, fwrite and fclose?