# How to write to textfile from checkboxes?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem to write to a textfile. The values where the user has clicked in one or more of the checkboxes in the form. When that is done it should print it to a textfile. So if a user mark meat and apple it should print it out to the textfile shoppingcart.txt.

I am very new to html, css and php. The code is below what i achieved so far.

```
<article class="article">

<p>What in the store and their prices</p>

<?php


foreach($file as $line) {
echo $line;
}

?>

<p> Below you can order some things!</p>


<form method="post" action="">

<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="meat"<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="apple"<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="drinks"<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">


<?php
$myfile = fopen("shoppingcart.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file");

fwrite($myfile

?>
</form>
```

What shall i write in the php section below the form?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php. Also note the flags `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX`.

Comment: you might want to learn a little about form processing in php before going any further with your script.

Comment: You probably want to use `SESSIONS` for this as well, not a text file. If 2 users are at your site at the same time and you write to `shoppingcart.txt` you wont be able tell who wants what.

Comment: similar question: maybe interesting? : [Store clicks inside .txt/.php file on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28918002/3184785)

Answer (score 0):

Here is very basic working example. You can use it as a start to add more interesting functionality :)

```
<article class="article">

    <p>What in the store and their prices</p>

    <?php
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            $result_string = '';
            foreach($_POST as $item) {
                $result_string .= $item."\n";
            }            
            file_put_contents('shoppingcart.txt', $result_string , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        }
    ?>

    <p> Below you can order some things!</p>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meat" value="meat"<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="apple" value="apple"<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="drinks" value="drinks"<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</article>
```

Comment: Better lock the file as well; `LOCK_EX`. Also it will be impossible to tell one user's order from anothers with this approach.

Comment: Thank you, jumanji. It works, only thing i notice is if i choose apple and drinks only one of them appends in textfile. dont know why, But ty for the example! :)

Comment: Ty chris85, i will ad LOCK_EX.

Comment: @IamnoobatSQL if I choose apple and drinks seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123" >
     Meat:  <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="meat"><br/> // name is cb[] , not cb
     Apple: <input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="apple"><br/>
     Drinks:<input type="checkbox" name="cb[]" value="drinks"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
$cb_v = isset($_POST['cb']) ? implode(',', $_POST['cb']) . PHP_EOL : '';
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

 if ($cb_v && $id) {
    file_put_contents("/tmp/shoppingcart{$id}.txt", $cb_v, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 }
```